# javafx desktop application accessing slow data from cloud database

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have created javafx desktop application and I am displaying values from cloud database.But the accessing values from cloud database takes more time to display on desktop application than local database.Is there any solution for fast MySQL query transaction?

Comment: It's really hard for us to help you with this kind of question. Sure, reading data from a local database is faster than reading data from e.g. cloud databases. Does the data have to be in a cloud database? Do you have 1 or n-clients cosuming that data?

Comment: Yes I have uploaded MySQL database on cloud and I have n_clients consuming that data.

Comment: If your data needs some time to be transferred from the cloud server to your client, you can't speed up the bandwith. Without your code or any other information like your internet connection speed e.g., it's really hard to helpf you.

Comment: I will try to find the solution.Thank you for your valuable time

Comment: Generally use PreparedStatements and show a progress bar to the client or some info about internet speed and expected time,so it has more suspense :).

Comment: Thank You.I have used prepare statement for each query.Progress bar is good option or I can display "Please wait" image.I have one more question - Is this right way to connect desktop application to cloud database?

Comment: Yeah, you can't say **in general**, that it's a good approach to connect to a cloud database - as always, it depends. In your described scenario, where several clients, which may be geographically separated, have to access the same data, it's a **proper approach** from my point of view!